# can't unregister click event in openlayers

Tags: event-handling, openlayers, markers

I am having issues with OpenLayers and unregistering the click events that are added to a layer. Basically, what I need to do is this:

When a user clicks on a marker, they get a bubble that has an "edit" link in it. The user clicks that and it creates a new layer on the map and then registers a click event to the map waiting for the user to click on the map. When they click somewhere on the map, it then moves the marker to where they clicked. This all works perfectly.

However, the issue is when the user clicks to edit the marker and then clicks on a button OUTSIDE OF THE MAP to cancel the action and NOT move the marker, the unregister of the click event doesn't work. They can still click on the map and it moves the marker.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
function move_marker(marker) {
    lmLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Landmark Creation",{displayInLayerSwitcher: false});
    map.addLayer(lmLayer);
    map.events.register("click", lmLayer, function(evt){
        var pixel = new OpenLayers.Pixel(evt.clientX,evt.clientY);
        position = map.getLonLatFromPixel(pixel);
        marker.lonlat = pixel;
        marker.moveTo(pixel);
        marker.draw();
        lmLayer.redraw();
        OpenLayers.Event.stop(evt);
    });
}
function cancel_move() {  // this function is triggered by a button outside of the map element
    lmLayer = map.getLayersByName('Landmark Creation');
    lmLayer[0].events.unregister("click");
    map.events.unregister("click");
    map.removeLayer(lmLayer[0]);
}
```

As you can see in the cancel function, I am getting the layer by the layer name, which according to the console.log it is finding at index 0. I added the unregister to the lmLayer in hopes that would help, but so far, no luck. Then on the map element I add the unregister call and then finally I remove that new layer because we don't want it interfering.

I'd appreciate some feedback on this. I'm losing my mind.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to tell OpenLayers **which** *click* event you want it to unregister:

```
var method = function() {
    // Do stuff...
}

map.events.register('click', map, method);
map.events.unregister('click', map, method);
```

According to the OpenLayers.Events source it checks whether the `scope` and the `method` is present in the listener stack:

```
unregister: function (type, obj, func) {
    if (obj == null)  {
        obj = this.object;
    }
    var listeners = this.listeners[type];
    if (listeners != null) {
        for (var i=0, len=listeners.length; i<len; i++) {
   HERE --> if (listeners[i].obj == obj && listeners[i].func == func) { <-- HERE
                listeners.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
},
```

I hope that works for you :)

Comment: That's very insightful. I changed it so that it just runs the function called "move_click" and put all of the content of that function was directly adding to the event listener into that external function. Now, it does indeed kill the click event on the map for the moving of the marker. HOWEVER... now ALL click events on the map have been killed. Which means I can't go back and click on a different marker to get the infoWindow. I use the map element and then the layer as the object to set up the click event, so I did the same to unregister: `map.events.unregister('click',lmLayer,move_click);`

Comment: Why would the unregister remove all click events when I had defined the layer as the object? I even remove the "lmLayer" object after doing the unregister so it's not still sitting there.

Comment: I would use Firebug or similar and set a break point at the line `lmLayer[0].events.unregister(...)` and debug into OpenLayers and see what is happening. I am curious to why you have to add the event to both the map and the layer? Not that I know it should be wrong, but just curious :)

Comment: yeah I use Firebug extensively and it hasn't yielded anything. I changed the line to `map.events.register('click',map,move_click);` and `map.events.unregister('click',map,move_click);` which appears to not have affected the move code. I am able now to unregister the events and supposedly remove the layer but, if I try to go and click on another marker, I get the following error in Firebug: `this.blocks is null this.groupDiv.style.position="absolute...{block.div.removeChild(block.image);} in Openlayers.js (line 571)`.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you about that error. If you can post a live working example, we might be able to help you further.