# Openlayers 3 stop event propagation

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I joined two examples from openlayers examples [popup](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/popup.html) and [drawing features](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/draw-features.html). Now i want to stop on map click listener when i'm drawing features, so that popup doesn't show when i'm drawing.

Comment: you can look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7637560/cant-unregister-click-event-in-openlayers)

Comment: @AknKplnoglu nope, because OL3 is totally different from OL2…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unregister your `click` event when drawing:

```
var key = map.on('click', function(evt) { … });

// when drawing
map.unByKey(key);
```

See http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Object.html#on

Comment: what when i stop drawing, is there any other function that register event back or i must call var key = map.on('click', function(evt) { … }); again